# Visual Studio 2019 generate executable filesize always multiple of 512 bytes

Tags: visual-studio-2019, executable, zero-padding

I was wondering if there is a technical explanation of Visual Studio executables file size is always a multiple of 512 bytes. In order to reach the wanted size, Visual Studio adds zero padding to the tail of the executable. Is there an advantage to have this? Is it controllable?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206312/for-what-reason-would-i-choose-a-c-sharp-compiler-file-alignment-setting-other-t